# Substitution $x=\sinh(\theta)$ and $y=\cosh(\theta)$ to $(1+x^{2})y'-2xy=(1+x^{2})^{2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

After this substitution I got to the point

$$\cosh^6 (\theta)y'-\sinh(2\theta)-\cosh^4 (\theta)=0$$

and now let

$$z=\cosh^2 (\theta)$$

so
$$z^3 y'-z^2-\sinh(2\theta)=0$$

but then I started to question my substitution, look at the graph [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Arcsinh%28x%29=Arccosh%28x%29). Is the substitution even possible? Can we actually even get $\textrm{arcsinh}(x)=\textrm{arccosh}(y)$? From the graph in WA, it seems like the hypergeometric sin/cosh do not even cross so the substition in the title is wrong or?

*Again from the book, now on page 644.*

Comment: Which book are you talking about?

Comment: @Peter: the foreign course book [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-1.1020/esite), not available in English (sorry).

Comment: I gave you a solution but I don't know how your solution would work. I'll think about it and edit ASAP.

Comment: Solution from my uni is [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-1.1020/viikkoharjoitukset/Mat-1_1020_mallit_av7.pdf), p. 636-637 (course book) mention something called `"variation of constant"` -- I have never understood the term, apparently just first-order linear DY? For future random walkers, I instruct to read the answers and the wikipedia -- I think the book is incomprehensible at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain the idea of the "*varioidaan vakiota*" that is stated in your .pdf. The idea traces back to Legendre, which used it to solve linear ODEs.

We have the equation

$$y'-\frac{2xy}{1+x^2}=1+x^2$$

We first solve the homogeneous equation

$$y'-\frac{2xy}{1+x^2}=0$$

$$y'=\frac{2xy}{1+x^2}$$

$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

$$\log y = \log(1+x^2)+C_1$$

$$ y = C(1+x^2)$$

What Legendre thinks now, which Spiegel says "in first sight, seems ridiculous is":

Let's assume $C$ is not constant, but rather variable. What will this new function $C(x)$ be so that

$$y = C(x)(1+x^2)$$

is a solution to our original equation?

So in your case we have that, differentiating produces

$$ y' = C'(x)(1+x^2)+C(x) 2x$$

But from our equation we have that $y'=\dfrac{2xy}{1+x^2}+(1+x^2)$ and that 
$ \dfrac{y}{1+x^2} = C(x)$

So plugging this in we have

$$y' = C'(x)(1+x^2)+\frac{2xy}{1+x^2}$$

So that, comparing to our original equation we have $C'(x) = 1$ or $C(x) = x+C_1$, so that our solution is

$$y = (x+C_1)(1+x^2)$$

Hope this helped clear out the "*varioidaan vakiota*" issue. For more infor refer to Spiegel's book on Differential Equations, page 202.

---

You have

$$(1+x^2)y' -2xy = (1+x^2)^2$$

or

$$(1+x^2)\dfrac{dy} {dx} -2xy = (1+x^2)^2$$

$$\dfrac{dy} {dx} -\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}y = 1+x^2$$

You can solve this by the integrating factor $$\exp\left(-\log\left(1+x^2\right)\right)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$$ which will give

$$\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\dfrac{dy} {dx} -\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}y = 1$$

$$\left(\dfrac{y}{1+x^2}\right)' = 1$$

$$\dfrac{y}{1+x^2} = x+C$$
$$y = (x+C)(1+x^2)$$

Comment: ...sorry what does the last sentence actually mean? Can you solve it that way?

Comment: @hhh I've been looking at the problem and the substitution is IMO a waste of time, since what it only helps is into seeing what integrating factor to use, which is $$\frac{1}{{{{\cosh }^2}\theta }} = \frac{1}{{1 + {x^2}}}$$ so the problem is solved in the same manner either way. If you want I can order my thoghts on the substitution and post it.

Comment: The `"integrating factor"` is my weakest link for sure, not sure how with different differentials. I think it would be good idea to somehow clarify the final sentence, now it is a bit separate from the other part of the answer.

Comment: @hhh Added info on your doubt. Any problem, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is a [linear differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation). In your case, it may be wise to skip the beginning of the Wikipedia article and go directly to "first order equation".

Comment: ...any idea why my school solution mentions the method `"variation of parameters"` needed to solve the problem? I think they referring to this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) by the term `"variation of constant"` (free translation). I can get the same solution without at least explicitly using some variation of parameters -method.

Comment: Moved this point to this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110884/variation-of-constant-method-to-solve-linear-dys) to keep questions specific.